# How does tf.keras.Model tell between features and label(s) in tf.data.Dataset and in TFRecords?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets, tf.keras

I'm trying to create `tfrecords` files from CSV data, then I want to use `tf.data.TFRecordDataset()` to create `Dataset` from them, and then feed the `Dataset` to `tf.keras.Model`. (In fact I'm using [spark-tensorflow-connector](https://github.com/tensorflow/ecosystem/tree/master/spark/spark-tensorflow-connector) to create `tfrecords` files directly from Spark Dataframes.)

In the [`fit()` method of `tf.keras.Model`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model?hl=en#fit), the argument `x` is the Input data. It could be:

> A tf.data dataset. Should return a tuple of either (inputs, targets)
>   or (inputs, targets, sample_weights).

Q1: **Is this where `tf.keras.Model` knows where to separate the features and the labels?** i.e., the features are the `inputs`, the labels are the `targets`.

However in some examples, I could not see any "tuple" in the building of either the `tfrecords` files or the `tf.data.Dataset`. For example, in the following [example](https://github.com/PacktPublishing/What-s-New-in-TensorFlow-2.0/blob/master/Chapter03/cifar10/create_tfrecords_from_cifar10.py),

```
def convert_to_tfrecord(input_files, output_file):
  """Converts a file to TFRecords."""
  print('Generating %s' % output_file)
  with tf.io.TFRecordWriter(output_file) as record_writer:
    for input_file in input_files:
      data_dict = read_pickle_from_file(input_file)
      data = data_dict[b'data']
      labels = data_dict[b'labels']
      num_entries_in_batch = len(labels)
      for i in range(num_entries_in_batch):
        example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(
            feature={
                'image': _bytes_feature(data[i].tobytes()),
                'label': _int64_feature(labels[i])
            }))
        record_writer.write(example.SerializeToString())
```

...

```
# Read dataset from tfrecords
dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(tfrecords_files)
```

Q2: **So how does this [`tf.keras.models.Sequential()` model](https://github.com/PacktPublishing/What-s-New-in-TensorFlow-2.0/blob/master/Chapter03/cifar10/cifar10_classification.py) know where to find the features and where to find the labels?** Why the model wouldn't take 'label' as a data feature?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to consider the full code example, i.e. the other files where the training is done etc. The main thing is the `parse_and_decode` function in [this file](https://github.com/PacktPublishing/What-s-New-in-TensorFlow-2.0/blob/master/Chapter03/cifar10/cifar10_data_prep.py) which parses the TFRecords file (without such a parse function, the data cannot be interpreted) and returns a tuple `image, label` for each piece of data. This function is then mapped over the dataset in the `create_datasets` function.

As such, the dataset that is given to `model.fit` is actually a dataset of tuples, and to the best of my knowledge, this is exactly what the model will assume if you provide a `tf.data.Dataset` as input to the `fit` function -- a dataset of tuples `inputs, labels`. So the first will be taken as input to the model, the second as target for the loss function.

Comment: Thanks! So does this mean, no matter I use `tfrecords` files or other file formats to create `tf.data` datasets, I should always use something like `dataset.map(self._parse_and_decode)` to return a dataset of tuples `inputs, labels` before feeding to `Model.fit()`?

Comment: Previously I created a `tf.data` dataset from `inputs, labels` tuples directly by `train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((train_model_input, train[target].to_numpy()))`, where `train_model_input` is a dict of input features: {name: numpy array}. It works. Is this a wrong way to do it?

Comment: `from_tensor_slices` works fine the way it is -- as in your example, you can just give it a tuple directly. However, `.tfrecords` files are saved in a byte format that needs to be parsed/interpreted first -- the job of the parse function is to do just that. In a way, this function needs to invert the `tf.train.Example` encoding stuff in the code you posted in the question.

Answer (score -1):

In this example,

```
            feature={
                'image': _bytes_feature(data[i].tobytes()),
                'label': _int64_feature(labels[i])
            }))
```

Here, `image` and `label` is a tuple where image has `byte` type and labels have `int64` type. YOu can read more [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/tfrecord#tfexample).